# Call Service function in stateProvider's resolve from module.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to transform a modal into a page. The modal data is filled with a function called `fillProperties`. Here's the old service with a modal:

```
// BEFORE
angular.module('mda')
  .service('visualizationModalService', ['$rootScope', 'nsjRouting', 'moment', 'toaster', '$uibModal', '$q', '$injector', '$filter',
    function ($rootScope, nsjRouting, moment, toaster, $uibModal, $q, $injector, $filter) {

      var fillProperties = function (specialEntity, scope) {
        // important stuff
      }

      var selfService = {
        open: function (solicitation, scope) {
          return $uibModal.open({
            template: require('html-loader!./visualization.modal.html'),
            controller: ['entity', '$uibModalInstance', '$injector', 'toaster', '$scope', '$rootScope', function (entity, $uibModalInstance, $injector, toaster, $scope, $rootScope) {
              // LOTS OF CODE
            }],
            controllerAs: "$ctrl",
            resolve: {
              entity: function () {
                entity = angular.copy(solicitation);
                return fillProperties(entity, scope); // important function call!
              }
            }
          });
        }
      };

      return selfService;
    }]);
```

You can see there's a `fillProperties` function call in the resolve.

I substituted the above with a service and a controller in a more separate manner:

```
// AFTER
angular.module('mda')
  .service('visualizationService', ['$rootScope', 'nsjRouting', 'moment', 'toaster', '$uibModal', '$q', '$injector', '$filter',
    function ($rootScope, nsjRouting, moment, toaster, $uibModal, $q, $injector, $filter) {

      var fillProperties = function (specialEntity, $scope) {
        // important stuff
      }

    }])

angular.module('mda')
  .controller('visualizationFormShowController', [
    '$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'entity', 'toaster', '$injector', 'visualizationService', function (
      $scope, $stateParams, $state, entityService, entity, toaster, $injector, visualizationService) {
      // LOTS OF CODE 
    }]);
```

The problem is, I need to execute this `fillProperties` function, which was previously being called in a resolve, as you can see in the old code, but I don't know exactly how to do it in the new code version. I'm trying to do it in a config file:

```
angular.module('mda')
    .config(['$stateProvider', 'nsjRoutingProvider', function ($stateProvider, nsjRoutingProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('meurh_solicitacoes_show', {
                url: "/visualizations?/:visualization/",
                resolve: {
                    entity: function () {
                        entity = angular.copy(solicitation);
                        return fillProperties(entity, scope);
                    }
                },
                template: require('html-loader!./show.html'),
                controller: 'visualizationFormShowController',
                controllerAs: 'vslztns_frm_shw_cntrllr',
            })
    }]);
```

but I receive an error of undefined function with the above approach. Is there a way to access the service function and its properties in the resolve of the config? Or any other better approaches?

Comment: How do you provide `specialEntity` to the `resolve` method in config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you get `specialEntity` in your `resolve`, so far you can call service method like this:

Your service:

```
app.service('visualizationModalService', ['$rootScope', function () {
      var self = this;

      self.fillProperties = function (entity) {
       alert("fillProperties is called with data = " + entity);
      }
 }]);
```

and config:

```
 resolve: {
      entity: function (visualizationModalService) {              
          return visualizationModalService.fillProperties("someData");
      }
  },
```

<kbd>[Some plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SO5jwgK2R40kRLdW)</kbd>

---

A side note:

> I want to transform a modal into a page.

Worth to use [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) so you can call the component in the controller or modal

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to access the service function and its properties in the resolve of the config?*

Services can be injected into resolve functions the same way they are injected into controllers:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', 'nsjRoutingProvider', function ($stateProvider, nsjRoutingProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('meurh_solicitacoes_show', {
        url: "/visualizations?/:visualization/",
        resolve: {
            entity: ['visualizationService', function (visualizationService) {

                //Use the service here

                return promiseOrValue;
            }]
        },
        template: require('html-loader!./show.html'),
        controller: 'visualizationFormShowController',
        controllerAs: 'vslztns_frm_shw_cntrllr',
    })
}]);
```

Keep on mind that `$scope` is not injectable into resolve functions.